# Ignore text from dot to a specific character with regex python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have a text like this:

```
text = "Text1.
        Textt « text2 »
        Some other text"
```

i want a regex code that is able to delete the text inside the quotes and the text before it till the dot.

so the output be like that :

```
text = "Text1.
    Some other text"
```

the code am stuck into :

```
text= re.sub(r'\s*.*?»', '', text)
```

what the code actually does is delete a more than expected here's an example :

```
text="Text1.
        Textt « text2 »
        Some other text
        Textt « text3 »
        other text"
```

the output i get is like this :

```
text="Text1.
    other text"
```

Comment: You probably want `\..*?»` as your RE, with the re.DOTALL option enabled so that `.*?` also matches newlines.

Comment: Your code seems to work, could you explain the difference between the actual and the expected output ?

Comment: It seems to work right? https://ideone.com/rw6sy9

Comment: the code seems to work but i have a long text and it deletes a lot of text, so i thought something wrong with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'(\.)[^.]*«[^«»]*»', r'\1', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bTQufn/4).

- `(\.)` - Group 1 (`\1` in the replacement refers to this captured value): a dot
- `[^.]*` - zero or more chars other than a `.`
- `«[^«»]*»` - a  substring between `«` and `»` without other `«` and `»` inside.

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/VHgzcS):

```py
import re
text = "Text1.\n        Textt « text2 »\n        Some other text"
print( re.sub(r'(\.)[^.]*«[^«»]*»', r'\1', text) )
```

Comment: @AdilKasbaoui Ok, you edited the question and now it is rather unclear. `(\.)[\s\S]*«[^«»]*»` [would work](https://regex101.com/r/bTQufn/3) for your example, but not sure it will work for the real input. The final solution will probably need to rely on more context.

Comment: @AdilKasbaoui It seems you need to add *actual rules* to explain what needs to be done.

Comment: @AdilKasbaoui Then use `re.sub(r'(\.)[^.]*«[^«»]*»', r'\1', text)`, the answer is corrected.

Comment: @AdilKasbaoui Yes, it is easy: `re.sub(r'([.?!])[^?!.]*«[^«»]*»', r'\1', text)`. I suspected this follow-up, that is my solution is based on a capturing group + backreference, it can be expanded.

Answer (score 2):

You may use:

```sh
import re

text = '''Text1.
       Textt « text2 »
       Some other text'''

text = re.sub(r'\.[^«]*«[^»]*»', '.', text)

print (text)
```

To get this output:

```sh
Text1.
    Some other text
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/c9uApR/1)

**RegEx Explained:**

- `\.`: Match a dot
- `[^«]*`: Match 0 or more characters that are not `«`
- `«`: Match a `«`
- `[^»]*`: Match 0 or more characters that are not `»`
- `»`: Match a `»`

We just replace this matched text with a single `dot` to get our desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use `split`

```
text = "Text1. Textt « text2 » Some other text"

text = text.split('«')[0].split('.')+'.' + text.split('»')[1] 

print(text)
```

output:

```
"Text1. Some other text"
```